# The bucket you are attempting to access must beźaddressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Code is available at https://github.com/dorian/magic

When doing `image_tag image` I get:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/magic.doma.io/iB68ze7FHdf8zYzoGrS4FzCP?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22Screen%20Shot%202018-04-06%20at%2011.19.32%20AM.png%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27Screen%2520Shot%25202018-04-06%2520at%252011.19.32%2520AM.png&response-content-type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI4IE6Y56GAUDFDGQ%2F20180411%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180411T093708Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=c611a8262d6bc60467b3b4b3aa49be649407e1ce2264927c34b895fea75edb19

Here is how I use ActiveStorage:

`config/storage.yml`:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  region: us-east-1
  bucket: magic.doma.io
```

`app/controller/ads_controller.rb`:

```
@ad.images.attach(ad_params[:images])
```

`app/views/ads/show.html.slim`:

`= image_tag image`

`app/views/ads/new.html.slim`:

`= f.file_field :images, multiple: true`

Comment: Are we suppose to go through your github project to find out where you are using `image_tag image`? Please provide some context in the body of your question

Comment: @Cyzanfar I added the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure I was using the correct aws region, e.g. `us-east-2` and use a user-level access key on AWS (instead of a root key).